# Having an issue installing jitsi-meet?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-14.04, webrtc, npm-install, jitsi

I am facing a problem with Installing jitsi-meet , I have followed the instruction that you can find in this page [ my system is ubuntu 14.04]

https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet

and when I executed the npm install I had this stack trace :

```
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/jitsi-meet-logger
npm ERR! TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
npm ERR!     at Function.keys (native)
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:708:24)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:638:10
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:142:7)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-31-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /videochat/jitsi-meet
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! type called_on_non_object
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/jQuery-Impromptu
npm ERR! TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
npm ERR!     at Function.keys (native)
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:708:24)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:638:10
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:142:7)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-31-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /videochat/jitsi-meet
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! type called_on_non_object
```

and it got stuck , is there anyother way to install jitsi-meet and make it working ??

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Node and npm versions you're using are way too old. In order to build Jitsi Meet you need at least Node 6 and npm 3: https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet#building-the-sources

Comment: Thanks it did work , but I enconuntered a new problem now after following the steps from this site : 
http://cheenwe.cn/2016-04-29/Ubuntu-Install-JitsiMeet/#install-prosody ,
I have a problem with jicofo :
Jicofo 2017-07-23 09:01:48.655 SEVERE: [30] org.jitsi.meet.ComponentMain.call().278 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused), host:10.64.5.89, port:5347

Answer (score 0):

Latest Jitsi works on node `lts` version. If you using an ubuntu environment then you have to install `n` and after that, you can easily change your node enviroment.

Visit :- https://github.com/tj/n